# How to use Dial up modem for VOIP to PSTN calls?

Tags: modem, voip, dial-up

I am new to asterisk freePBX and I want to establish calls between softphone to normal PSTN connections. So I am wondering is this possible or not? can this dial up modem will do it?

It has two FXS ports one is for Internet and another for normal telephone.

THE REAL QUESTION I NEED ANSWER IS: Will this telephony cards help me dial any PSTN phone lines across the PSTN network? )Not just the telephone present in the room with the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want that your *Asterisk PBX* use a dial-up modem as a **PSTN analog card** in order to make and receive calls, your Asterisk PBX convert it to SIP and put the call on a softphone.

The big problem is that Asterisk is unable to "talk" to the modem card because there are hundreds of different models and Asterisk doesn't have the drivers for each one.

There is a cheap card, [the X100P card](http://www.x100p.com/products/FXO.php) that you can use for that. Actually is a V.92 softmodem based upon the Intel 537 or MD3200 chipset.

This card is full-duplex which is required for VoIP applications and Asterisk has specific drivers Zaptel for this card.

It is possible to use a card with the same chipset however to get that the Zaptel driver recognize it you need to make a modifications to the driver and it means to fiddle with the source code of the driver.

There are also FXO ATA's that let you get the same result adding the ATA to your network.

Comment: Basically what you are suggesting look exactly same as X100P, the thing is i never used it for VOIP or any other purpose other than internet connection. let me give a try and get back to you...

Comment: OK i should have listened to you... i can't get it work... asterisk is not detecting anything... so the card you are mentioning, are you absolutely sure it will work? how to install and config? setup process? please guide me jc... else point me a card that will work...

Comment: well read the documentation of X100P card and i see this is how it works PSTN-->Card(with IP PBX)-->home telephone. but i don't want that... call should be dialed from PSTN-->remote landline. please JCbermu help me

Comment: @AccountUnknown This is from the **Description**:  
Authentic X100P allows Asterisk to **make calls** to or **receive calls** from a **traditional analog phone line**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it and it doesn't take that much bandwidth, BUT, you might get unbearable latency causing you to either have insane delay, your message might not get through at all or you'd be disconnecting all the time.

That beeing said, the VoIP program you would have best chances with is [Mumble](http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Main_Page), it's open source and 100% free to use and run a no limit server(the server should not be hosted on a dial-up modem).

I didn't know that dial-up still was a thing, but if you can have something else, then my advice is that you upgrade your internet to broadband, if you can't then it can't be helped.

But yeah, any other VoIP than Mumble can be unstable, I'm not saying that Mumble is gonna be stable, I have no idea, but yeah, Mumble sends the least packages of all what I know of, I could be wrong.

I hope that you find this helpful,

The best way is to test it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer FrozdY, this is only to test whether i can use this feature with this device or not. i read a cook book [link](http://pbxbook.com/voip/asteopen.html) is this setup allow me to config my dial up devicee properly?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not used to linux as a whole, so I have no idea unfortunately

Comment: @Frozdy He wants to use the modem as a PSTN analog card for an Asterisk PBX, **not to access internet trough dial-up**.

Comment: @jcbermu Then I'm lost.

Comment: @Frozdy Asterisk as a PBX is able to interact easily with SIP softphones, but to interact with PSTN lines needs *special hardware*. The question was about using a modem as a PSTN hardware so Asterisk can use it send / receive calls.